# XPath query: Query not working as expected

Tags: xpath

I was learning XPath using the following xml document: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp

Now, when I execute the query:

```
bookstore/book/author[contains(.,'G')]
```

I get the result: `Giada De Laurentiis, James McGovern` as expected. Now, since `contains()` returns a boolean value, I expected the following query to return all authors:

```
bookstore/book/author[true]
```

however, it returns an empty set. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I expected the following query to return all authors:
>
> ```
> bookstore/book/author[true]
> ```
>
> however, it returns an empty set. Can somebody explain?

The above expression selects all `bookstore/book/author` elements that have a child element named `true`. In the provided XML document no `author` element has a child named `true` -- therefore the XPath expression selects nothing.

**In a comment the OP asks**:

> But why does `bookstore/book/author[true]` not work, since if is
>   similar to the situation when the `contains()` always returns true

`contains()` never returns (the string) "true" -- it returns the *boolean* value `true()` -- this is different from the string "true".

**Explanation**:

You are confused by the fact that the serialization of the boolean value `true()` to sting is the string "true".

This fact doesnt mean that the string "true" and the boolean value `true()` are identical.

Answer (score 4):

you need `bookstore/book/author`

**UPDATE**: to pass `true` into `XPATH` you have to use `bookstore/book/author[true()]`
`author[true]` just means that you want to get all `author` element which has `true` subelement.

You can check it yourself, try expressions

`bookstore/book[author1]` vs `bookstore/book[author]`

First one returns you nothing, because there's no `book` element with `author1` subelements. Second one returns you all elements. But if you remove `author` subnodes from some of books nodes, you'll get only those having `author` subnode.

So if you take xml like this

```
<bookstore>
    <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    </book>
</bookstore>
```

then
`bookstore/book[author]` returns

```
<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>
```

and `bookstore/book[title]` returns

```
<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
</book>
```

Comment: Roman Perker: yes, I know. But why does bookstore/book/author[true] not work, since if is similar to the situation when the contains() always returns true

Comment: Although it seems that in some implementations (e.g. Zorba) `true` is actually the same as `true()`